# SQL Server -- Group by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a 180k+ row SQL Server table that I am trying to run some basic analytics on (I am new to SQL).

Basically, I want to group rows by the `YYYY-MM` in their timestamp and count them.

This is what I have so far, but it's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(7), [dbname].[column name], 12) [Month], 
    SUM(Amount) [TotalAmount]
FROM
    [dbname]
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR(7), [dbname].[column name], 12);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would separate the month and year into separate columns:

```
select year(col), month(col), sum(amount)
from [dbname] t
group by year(col), month(col)
order by year(col), month(col);
```

If you really want YYYY-MM:

```
select convert(varchar(7), col, 120) as yyyymm, sum(amount)
from [dbname] t
group by convert(varchar(7), col, 120)
order by yyyymm;
```

Comment: That command will break out year and month even if they are in the same field?

Comment: Yes, each date component is a separate column in the first query.

Comment: I don't really need YYYY-MM.  I am trying the first suggestion you made.  Where would I put the table name?